# how to decode this string present in utf 16 using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, decode, utf-16

how to decode this string present in utf-16  using python3

```
"b'\\xff\\xfeS\\x00H\\x00A\\x00D\\x00E\\x00K\\x00 \\x00D\\x00E\\x00E\\x00E\\x00P\\x00'"
```

tried this but getting the error  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

`a.rstrip("\n").decode("utf-16")`

Comment: Remove the extra " before and after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a string which has been created by calling `str` on encoded text (a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes) instance).  Like this:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> bs = s.encode('utf-16')
>>> bs
b'\xff\xfea\x00b\x00c\x00'
>>> str(bs)
"b'\\xff\\xfea\\x00b\\x00c\\x00'"   # <- the 'b' is *inside* the outer quotes
```

The bytes can be recovered by calling [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on the string, and then the bytes may be decoded back to a sring by calling their decode method.

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "b'\\xff\\xfeS\\x00H\\x00A\\x00D\\x00E\\x00K\\x00 \\x00D\\x00E\\x00E\\x00E\\x00P\\x00'"
>>> bs = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> bs
b'\xff\xfeS\x00H\x00A\x00D\x00E\x00K\x00 \x00D\x00E\x00E\x00E\x00P\x00'
>>> original = bs.decode('utf-16')
>>> original
'SHADEK DEEEP'
```

This is a workaround.  The correct solution is to prevent `str` being called on the bytes instance in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Consider you can edit this text, change it into this:

```py
r = b'\xff\xfeS\x00H\x00A\x00D\x00E\x00K\x00 \x00D\x00E\x00E\x00E\x00P\x00'
print(r.decode('utf-16')) # SHADEK DEEEP
```

Notice the change between

## String

```
"b'\\xff\\xfeS\\x00H\\x00A\\x00D\\x00E\\x00K\\x00 \\x00D\\x00E\\x00E\\x00E\\x00P\\x00'"
```

## Bytes of string

```
b'\\xff\\xfeS\\x00H\\x00A\\x00D\\x00E\\x00K\\x00 \\x00D\\x00E\\x00E\\x00E\\x00P\\x00'
```

## Bytes of hex

```py
b'\xff\xfeS\x00H\x00A\x00D\x00E\x00K\x00 \x00D\x00E\x00E\x00E\x00P\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have some extra `"` in the beginning and end of what you want to decode.

This works fine for me:

```py
>>> b'\\xff\\xfeS\\x00H\\x00A\\x00D\\x00E\\x00K\\x00 \\x00D\\x00E\\x00E\\x00E\\x00P\\x00'.decode('utf-16')
>>> '硜晦硜敦屓へ䠰硜〰屁へ䐰硜〰居へ䬰硜〰尠へ䐰硜〰居へ䔰硜〰居へ倰硜〰'
```

**Update:**
As Reznik suggested, you should deleted extra `\` characters.

Comment: i need that in english

Comment: Python is not going to translate a string for you. The encoded byte is in Chinese not English!